# AnyLogic Barchart : How to start with value other than 0

Tags: bar-chart, anylogic

I want my bar chart to start with value other than 0.

I already set up variable value as 2 and my service from process modeling library will update variable value overtime.

Every time I play the simulation, the bar chart always start at 0 value not start at 2 value

I am still new to AnyLogic. I've tried google for days, but I couldn't find the answer or tutorial I'm looking for.

Here is my code in process modeling onExit:

```
nValue++;

double i = nValue;

barChart.add(i);
```

What I want is

Bar chart currently shows 0 (Start value) to 2 (Value I set).

I expect Bar chart to start at 2 (Value I set) to nValue (Value updated overtime)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Am I correct that you want the scale to only show 2......n ?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible, see my answer below...

Comment: in fact it is possible, but you have to generate your own barChart using shapes... It would be quite more complicated... I didn't understand the question the first time :(

Comment: @Felipe Is there any tutorial or guide that I can follow?

Comment: of course there's no tutorial on that... But I will do one when i have time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this (this is just a photoshopped version of your screenshot):

[image: Bar Chart Mockup]

You can set a fixed scale in AnyLogic here:

[image: Bar Chart Properties]

However it seems that it is not possible to not include a 0 value inside the scale, your setting of 2 - something (let's use 100 here), brings the following error:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: root:
The interval [minimum,maximum] must contain 0
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or some technical limitation. But in short: What you are trying to do doesn't work.